# Deleting files after download in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a application that lets a user download a file. After the download i want the file to be deleted. The end of my code is like this:

```
return Response::download(public_path() . '/uploads/_tmp/' . urldecode($filename));
```

which means that the function ends on the return an i am not able to delete the file. I have tried to call a 'after' filter on the route but then the file gets deleted to quickly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want the temporary file that PHP creates to be deleted, or the file that you have just download and put somewhere on your file system. Because the temporary file created and used by PHP in the download process is deleted by PHP automatically.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I personally use the following;

```
$response = Response::make(file_get_contents($path_to_file), $status_code, $headers);
```

Status code is obviously the code which you want to return.

Within the $header parameter you can pass an array with the indexes Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

Then you can simply unlink $path_to_file and return $response.

---

Much easier way of deleting a file would be to use Jon's answer for versions of Laravel > 4.0.

You can use `deleteFileAfterSend` http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses

```
return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 68):

You can use `deleteFileAfterSend` http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses

`return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);`

Comment: See @cbloss793 comment below "This works in Laravel 4.2. Just place it in the controller instead of the app/start/global.php."

Comment: DeleteFileAfterSend(true) works great on Laravel 5.3 as well. Although the documentation doesn't state anything about it, you can still use it. Maybe it will be deprecated anytime soon.

Comment: Note that `deleteFileAfterSend(true)` is actually a Symfony feature (part of `HttpFoundation`), which appears to have been added in [2014](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/1fff15864697c6078a74d0a53dab79a5a88803f4).

Comment: Nice! This even works when streaming a file, i.e. `return response()->file(...)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! 7 years later and you still helped me! I wonder why this was removed from the Laravel docs?!

Answer (score 9):

Simply use this line of code:

`return response()->download($file_path)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);`

Here, inside download function the file path will be passed as an argument. Let's say for an example you want to backup your database in a file and also want to delete with downloading:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_h-i');
$pub_path = public_path();
$file_path = $pub_path . '/application/db_backups/' . $date . '.sql';
$output = shell_exec('mysqldump -h58.84.34.65 -uwsit -pwsit97480 websms > ' . $file_path);
return response()->download($file_path)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: Code only answers are not always easy to understand to others. It would be great if you could add a short comment on how your proposal solves the OP's problem

Answer (score 9):

If you want to delete the source file after downloading, simply write it as follows

```
return response()->download($filePath)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$filename = storage_path() . '/testing.txt';

App::finish(function($request, $response) use ($filename)
{
    unlink($filename);
});

return Response::download($filename);
```

Comment: Try explaining your answer.

Comment: This works in Laravel 4.2. Just place it int he controller instead of the app/start/global.php. Brilliant!

Comment: Don't use if you have laravel > 5.0

Comment: I second @CommandZ, use Jon's method above for any version 5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

For [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8) use [stream download](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads). In the callback function, delete the file after echo the contents.

Let's take a look at the solution:

```php
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($pathToTheFile) {
    echo Storage::get($pathToTheFile);
    Storage::delete($pathToTheFile);
}, 'my-awesome-file-name');
```

> I don't know if it works for the oldest or the latest versions.

Answer (score -8):

```
unlink('./path/filename.extension');
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could add a little explanation to your answer, not just a one-liner

Comment: In the question he returns the response. This code would never even run.